# How to resolve an sqlite dependency inside python virtual env?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, matrix-synapse

I am trying to run the Matrix Synapse chat server by following this tutorial:
https://www.informaticar.net/install-matrix-synapse-on-centos-8/

It uses virtualenv to separate out python packages for this installation.

However when I start the server it complains about sqlite being too old.
So as not to get blocked I switch to using postgres as a backend, however I wonder what's the best way to point virtualenv and python and pip to the right version of sqlite.
It looks like sqlite is already installed system-wide (Package sqlite-3.7.17-8.el7_7.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version)
and I was only able to fetch a fairly old version of sqlite wrapper with pip:

```
pip install -U pysqlite3

Collecting pysqlite3
  Using cached pysqlite3-0.4.6.tar.gz
  WARNING: Legacy build of wheel for 'pysqlite3' created no files.
 Running setup.py clean for pysqlite3
Failed to build pysqlite3
```

1. What is the recommended way to link/point virtualenv to the correct/recent version of sqlite?
2. How do I verify which version of sqlite is configured for the current virtualenv?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Python comes with built-in SQLite support since 2.4 AFAIR. No need to install this package.

Comment: it wasn't compaining about sqlite not being there at all, but about sqlite version being too old. I'll reinstall and I'll try to reproduce the exact error again (i've switched to using postgres for now)

Comment: Like I said I dont have the version with sqlite handy, but the error is still in the logs: "2021-09-24 14:01:59,878"